# How to initialize an empty array of object with a predefined array?

Tags: reactjs, object

I am facing lot of issue to initialize an array of object with a predefined array. I am not being able to copy that array to my new array of objects. If anyone knows it then let me know.

`admins` is basically an array which contains string items like `["hello","hii","sup",....]`

```
var admins = ["hello","hii","sup"];
var obj = [];

for(var i=0; i<admins.length; i++)
{
    obj[i].name = admins[i];
}

console.log(obj);
```

"TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined"

Comment: What does ``admins`` look like?

Comment: `admins` is basically an array which contains string items like ["hello","hii","sup",....]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var newArray = admins.map((admin) => ({ name: admin }));
```

Comment: after reviewing the question again, this is the best answer +++1

Answer (score 1):

IMHO: use spread operator:

```js
const admins = ["John", "Doe", "Duck"];
const obj = [...admins].map(
  (admin) => ({ name: admin })
);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: How will this assign `name` property to each object in the new array?

Comment: @UmairSarfraz this is not clear if the OP want to set the name. The title says "initialize from predefined array".

Comment: How will I assign the `admins` values to the `name` field of the `obj` array of object??

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini The description says `initialize an array of object`

Comment: Edited to fullfill

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini Thanks for the edit. However, the spread operator is unnecessary in this case as you are already using a `map`.

Comment: If admin is an object it will make a copy, not a reference, spread operator is intended

Comment: Right, but `admins` is not an array of objects. It is an array of strings https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56541905/how-to-initialize-an-empty-array-of-object-with-a-predefined-array/56542069?noredirect=1#comment99665702_56541905

Answer (score -1):

Try out this

```
 var obj = [];

for (var i = 0; i < admins.length; i++) {
  let temp = {};
  temp["name"] = admins[i];
  obj.push(temp);
}

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to define the obj[i] to empty object (obj[i] = {}).

you are trying to access name property of undefined(obj[i] is undefined in your code).

```
var obj = [];

    for(var i=0; i<admins.length; i++)
    {
     obj[i] = {
      name: admins[i]
     }
   }

    console.log(obj);
```

Comment: This is the only answer that points to the right concept here which the questioner missed. Each element in the array needs to be an object, only then can one define obj[i].something! Don't know why people down-voted this!